# ARC error with FMDB class after changes to building settings to compile SQLCipher

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb, sqlcipher

I followed the tutorial for compiling SQLCipher on iOS devices using a binary located here: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-binaries-ios-and-osx/

I've made several changes to build settings, adding header search path and C flags. Then after testing a compile of the sqlcipher, i didn't get any errors with the binary, but errors that did not exist before with FMDB started showing up like this:

> FMDatabaseAdditions.m:137:19: Implicit declaration of function 'NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode' is invalid in C99`
>
> FMDatabaseAdditions.m:137:19: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC`
>
> FMDatabaseAdditions.m:137:15: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSString *__strong' with an expression of type 'int'`
>
> FMDatabaseAdditions.m:158:96: Values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead`
>
> FMDatabaseAdditions.m:161:28: Implicit declaration of function 'NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType' is invalid in C99`

Comment: Hey, @LibanAbdulle, check the answer bellow as solution! Because this answer resolve my problem!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This error occurs when you play with targets in your project. The  NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode is only needed when you compile project against Mac OS target and should not be used if target is iPhone. Actually, on the new versions of XCode it seems the error occurs even if your project is targeted as iPhone .
**Old answer:**

So we must rewrite applicationIDString implementation and put conditional flags:

```
    #if TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    - (NSString*)applicationIDString {
       NSString *s = NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode([self applicationID]);

       assert([s length] == 6);

       s = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)];


       return s;

    }
#endif
```

The condition if TARGET_OS_MAC will not replace the need of !TARGET_OS_IPHONE because TARGET_OS_IPHONE is actually a variant of  TARGET_OS_MAC. So to avoid compile errors, add #if TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE

Also below that part of code:

```
    - (void)setApplicationIDString:(NSString*)s {

       if ([s length] != 4) {
          NSLog(@"setApplicationIDString: string passed is not exactly 4 chars long. (was %ld)", [s length]);
       }
        #if TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
       [self setApplicationID:NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType([NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", s])];
       #endif
   }
```

**New answer:**

**I updated the code and rearranged methods to be more grouped on scope (conditions) in FMDatabaseAdditions.m** :

```
        #if SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER >= 3007017

        - (uint32_t)applicationID {

            uint32_t r = 0;

            FMResultSet *rs = [self executeQuery:@"pragma application_id"];

            if ([rs next]) {
                r = (uint32_t)[rs longLongIntForColumnIndex:0];
            }

            [rs close];

            return r;
        }

        - (void)setApplicationID:(uint32_t)appID {
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pragma application_id=%d", appID];
            FMResultSet *rs = [self executeQuery:query];
            [rs next];
            [rs close];
        }


        #if TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        - (NSString*)applicationIDString {
            NSString *s = NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode([self applicationID]);

            assert([s length] == 6);

            s = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)];


            return s;

        }

        - (void)setApplicationIDString:(NSString*)s {

            if ([s length] != 4) {
                NSLog(@"setApplicationIDString: string passed is not exactly 4 chars long. (was %ld)", [s length]);
            }

            [self setApplicationID:NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType([NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", s])];
        }


        #endif

        #endif
```

**Also to avoid other warnings I modified  FMDatabaseAdditions.h**

```
       #if SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER >= 3007017

        ///-----------------------------------
        /// @name Application identifier tasks
        ///-----------------------------------

        /** Retrieve application ID

         @return The `uint32_t` numeric value of the application ID.

         @see setApplicationID:
         */

        - (uint32_t)applicationID;

        /** Set the application ID

         @param appID The `uint32_t` numeric value of the application ID.

         @see applicationID
         */

        - (void)setApplicationID:(uint32_t)appID;

        #if TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        /** Retrieve application ID string

         @return The `NSString` value of the application ID.

         @see setApplicationIDString:
         */


        - (NSString*)applicationIDString;

        /** Set the application ID string

         @param string The `NSString` value of the application ID.

         @see applicationIDString
         */

        - (void)setApplicationIDString:(NSString*)string;
        #endif

        #endif
```

Comment: Maybe update your answer because this causes a new warning that the method declaration for "applicationIDString" is not found. I think maybe the if-endif could be moved, and we otherwise just return an default string?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a bug in FMDB (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/163) - the code in question is only meant to compile in OSX.